# faithful irreducible representation of linear algebraic group over reals

Tags: algebraic-groups

Is it true that if a linear algebraic group defined over $\mathbb{R}$ has a faithful irreducible representation, then it is reductive?

Comment: see http://mathoverflow.net/a/235657/89334

Comment: More precisely the answer is yes and the answer to the question linked by @user89334 gives the (standard) argument (using the action of the center of the unipotent radical).

Answer (score 0):

Being defined over $\mathbf{R}$ is not really an issue (since $\mathbf{R}$ is perfect). In fact, a linear algebraic group $G$ over a perfect field $k$ is reductive if and only if the group $G_K$ obtained by base change is reductive, where $K$ is an algebraic closure of $k$. So you may as well ask the question for linear algebraic groups over $\mathbf{C}$, or any algebraically closed field $k$.

Now suppose that $V$ is a faithful irreducible representation over the algebraically closed field $k$. Our goal is to argue that the unipotent radical $R$ of $G$ is trivial.

Since $R$ is unipotent, the *only* irreducible linear representation of $R$ is the trivial representation $k$. It follows that the space of $R$-fixed points $V^R$ is non-zero (this space is just the *socle* of $V$ as an $R$-module, and the socle is always non-zero).
Since $R$ is normal in $G$, the subspace $V^R$ is $G$-invariant. Since $V$ is an irreducible $G$-module, conclude that $V = V^R$, so that $R$ acts trivially on $V$. Since $V$ is a *faithful* representation for $G$, it now follows that $R$ is trivial, as required.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. I was dubious about the content, which you clarified in the first paragraph you wrote.